# How to connect to azure windows server VM using local user created inside VM

Tags: azure, authentication, virtual-machine, azure-bastion

I have created one local user inside windows server VM. I want to login to windows server VM using this local user using Azure bastion service. When I am trying to login, I am getting message that either machine is not reachable or credentials are not correct. (ofcourse I am using correct credentials, I reset password and tried but its still same, and VM is up and running)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer myself. Normal user(non-admin) which we will create, add that user in the Remote Desktop User group, and then try to login with Bastion service, it will be connected.